# Keycloak and postgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I have a question: When I connect my postgreSQL with keycloak using my own realm, and when I list the tables I get the tables of both realms. The master and the one that I just created.
Then I added a new user with postgreSQL and I couldn't find the user that I just created in both realms.
Also, I'm trying to see the tables in pgAdmin4 and I'm not able to establish a connection.
So far this is my docker image:

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres:15.6
    container_name: postgres_db
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB:test
      POSTGRES_USER: test
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: password

  keycloak_web:
    image: quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:23.0.7
    volumes:
      - ./realm-export.json:/opt/keycloak/data/import/realm.json
    container_name: keycloak_web
    environment:
      KC_DB: postgres
      KC_DB_URL: jdbc:postgresql://postgres:5432/keycloak
      KC_DB_USERNAME: test
      KC_DB_PASSWORD: password

      KC_HOSTNAME: localhost
      KC_HOSTNAME_STRICT: false
      KC_HOSTNAME_STRICT_HTTPS: false

      KC_LOG_LEVEL: info
      KC_METRICS_ENABLED: true
      KC_HEALTH_ENABLED: true
      KEYCLOAK_ADMIN: admin
      KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_PASSWORD: admin
    command: 
      - start-dev
      - --import-realm
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    ports:
      - 8180:8080

volumes:
  postgres_data:
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do with this steps

##### docker compose

```yaml
version: '3.8'

services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres:15.6
    container_name: postgres_db
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: keycloak
      POSTGRES_USER: keycloak
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: password

  pgadmin:
    image: dpage/pgadmin4
    container_name: pgadmin4_container
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "9090:80"
    environment:
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL: user-name@domain-name.com
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD: strong-password
    volumes:
      - pgadmin-data:/var/lib/pgadmin

  keycloak_web:
    image: quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:24.0.2
    container_name: keycloak_web
    environment:
      KC_DB: postgres
      KC_DB_URL: jdbc:postgresql://postgres:5432/keycloak
      KC_DB_USERNAME: keycloak
      KC_DB_PASSWORD: password

      KC_HOSTNAME: localhost
      KC_HOSTNAME_STRICT: false
      KC_HOSTNAME_STRICT_HTTPS: false

      KC_LOG_LEVEL: info
      KC_METRICS_ENABLED: true
      KC_HEALTH_ENABLED: true
      KEYCLOAK_ADMIN: admin
      KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_PASSWORD: admin
    command: start-dev
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    ports:
      - 8080:8080

volumes:
  postgres_data:
  pgadmin-data:
```

##### launch it

```
docker compose up -d
```

##### Check containers

```
docker ps -a
```

[image]

##### Check users for a specific realm

Login master

```
http://localhost:8080
```

Credential for master realm admin

```
username: admin
password: admin
```

[image]

##### Login pgAdmin

```
http://localhost:9090
```

Credential for pgAdmin

```
username: user-name@domain-name.com
password: strong-password
```

[image]

##### Connect Postgres

[image]

```
Host name/address: postgres_db
Maintenance database: keycloak
Username: keycloak
Password: password
```

[image]

##### Table access

[image]

##### User access

[image]

Comment: wow awesome response and it works finally! thank you for the help!

Comment: I am happy to hear you got it. Thanks for your acceptance and upvote. I also learned a lot of things from your question.